# PHP Exec() and Python script scaleability

Tags: php, python, exec

I have a php application that executes Python scripts via exec() and cgi.

I have a number of pages that do this and while I know WSGI is the better way to go long-term, I'm wondering if for a small/medium amount of traffic this arrangement is acceptable.

I ask because a few posts mentioned that Apache has to spawn a new process for each instance of the Python interpreter which increases overhead, but I don't know how significant it is for a smaller project.

Thank you.

Comment: personally I wouldnt do this if youre going to get more than a few concurrent users you can build up a tonne of orphan precesses pretty quick also your script can lock-up python totally and stop responding

Comment: for 'small' traffic, as hacky as this is, it shouldn't be a problem.

for 'medium' traffic, I wouldn't do this.  aside from the lockup concerns, you also have 'slow process' concerns , bots, etc - where reloads or traffic spikes will overload your machine.

it's pretty trivial to get wsgi running a python script in pyramid/bottle/etc these days. for small traffic you could probably use a crontab to just process stuff too, tasking stuff via a queue and dropbox in a database or the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.  So if I wanted to use WSGI would you recommend installing perhaps mod_wsgi (I use apache for PHP) and a web framework (like CherryPy)? Then instead of using exec() use some other PHP function to execute the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of CGI, server starts a copy of PHP interpreter every time it gets a request. PHP in turn starts Python process, which is killed after exec(). There is a huge overhead on starting two processes and doing all imports on every request.

In case of FastCGI or WSGI, server keeps couple processes warmed up (min and max amount of running processes is configurable), so at price of some memory you get rid of starting new process every time. However, you still have to start/stop Python process on every exec() call. If you can use a Python app without exec(), eg port PHP part to Python, it would boost performance a lot.

But as you mentioned this is a small project so the only important criteria is if your current server can sustain current load.